# I have a C hashing routine which is behaving strangely

Tags: c, hash

In this hashing routine:
1.) I am able to add strings.
2.) I am able to view my added strings.
3.) When I try to add a duplicate string, it throws me an error saying already present.
4.) But, when I try to delete the same string which is already present in hash table,
    then the lookup_routine calls hash function to get an index. At this time, it throws a   different hash index to the one it was already added. Hence, my delete routine is failing?

I am able to understand the reason why for same string, hash function calculates a different index each time (whereas the same logic works in view hash table routine)? Can someone help me?

## This is the Output, I am getting:

```
$ ./a

 Press 1 to add an element to the hashtable

 Press 2 to delete an element from the hashtable

 Press 3 to search the hashtable

 Press 4 to view  the hashtable

 Press 5 to exit

 Please enter your choice: 1

 Please enter the string :gaura

 enters in add_string

 DEBUG purpose in hash function:

 str passed = gaura
 Hashval returned in hash func= 1
 hashval = 1
 enters in lookup_string

 str in lookup_string = gaura
 DEBUG purpose in hash function:

 str passed = gaura
 Hashval returned in hash func= 1
 hashval = 1

 DEBUG ERROR :element not found in lookup string

 DEBUG Purpose

 NULL

 Inserting...

 DEBUG1 : enters here

 hashval = 1
 String added successfully

 Press 1 to add an element to the hashtable

 Press 2 to delete an element from the hashtable

 Press 3 to search the hashtable

 Press 4 to view  the hashtable

 Press 5 to exit

 Please enter your choice: 1

 Please enter the string :ayu

 enters in add_string

 DEBUG purpose in hash function:

 str passed = ayu
 Hashval returned in hash func= 1
 hashval = 1
 enters in lookup_string

 str in lookup_string = ayu
 DEBUG purpose in hash function:

 str passed = ayu
 Hashval returned in hash func= 1
 hashval = 1

 returns NULL in lookup_string

 DEBUG Purpose

 NULL

 Inserting...

 DEBUG2 : enters here

 hashval = 1
 String added successfully

 Press 1 to add an element to the hashtable

 Press 2 to delete an element from the hashtable

 Press 3 to search the hashtable

 Press 4 to view  the hashtable

 Press 5 to exit

 Please enter your choice: 1

 Please enter the string :gaurava

 enters in add_string

 DEBUG purpose in hash function:

 str passed = gaurava
 Hashval returned in hash func= 7
 hashval = 7
 enters in lookup_string

 str in lookup_string = gaurava
 DEBUG purpose in hash function:

 str passed = gaurava
 Hashval returned in hash func= 7
 hashval = 7

 DEBUG ERROR :element not found in lookup string

 DEBUG Purpose

 NULL

 Inserting...

 DEBUG1 : enters here

 hashval = 7
 String added successfully

 Press 1 to add an element to the hashtable

 Press 2 to delete an element from the hashtable

 Press 3 to search the hashtable

 Press 4 to view  the hashtable

 Press 5 to exit

 Please enter your choice: 4
 Index : i = 1   String = gaura  ayu
 Index : i = 7   String = gaurava

 Press 1 to add an element to the hashtable

 Press 2 to delete an element from the hashtable

 Press 3 to search the hashtable

 Press 4 to view  the hashtable

 Press 5 to exit

 Please enter your choice: 2

 Please enter the string you want to delete :gaura

 String entered = gaura
 enters in delete_string

 DEBUG purpose in hash function:

 str passed = gaura
 Hashval returned in hash func= 0
 hashval = 0
 enters in lookup_string

 str in lookup_string = gaura
 DEBUG purpose in hash function:

 str passed = gaura
 Hashval returned in hash func= 0
 hashval = 0

 DEBUG ERROR :element not found in lookup string

 DEBUG Purpose

 Item not present. So, cannot be deleted

 Item found in list: Deletion failed

 Press 1 to add an element to the hashtable

 Press 2 to delete an element from the hashtable

 Press 3 to search the hashtable

 Press 4 to view  the hashtable

 Press 5 to exit

 Please enter your choice:
==============================================================
```

My routine is pasted below:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

struct list
{ 
 char *string;
 struct list *next; 
};

struct hash_table
{
 int size;     /* the size of the table */
 struct list **table; /* the table elements */
}; 

struct hash_table * hashtable = NULL;

struct hash_table *create_hash_table(int size)
{
    struct hash_table *new_table;
    int i;

    if (size<1) return NULL; /* invalid size for table */

    /* Attempt to allocate memory for the table structure */
    if ((new_table = malloc(sizeof(struct hash_table))) == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }

    /* Attempt to allocate memory for the table itself */
    if ((new_table->table = malloc(sizeof(struct list *) * size)) == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }

    /* Initialize the elements of the table */
    for(i=0; i<size; i++) 
     new_table->table[i] = '\0';

    /* Set the table's size */
    new_table->size = size;

    return new_table;
}


unsigned int hash(struct hash_table *hashtable, char *str)
{
    printf("\n DEBUG purpose in hash function:\n");
    printf("\n str passed = %s", str);

    unsigned int hashval = 0;
    int i = 0;

    for(; *str != '\0'; str++)
    {
     hashval += str[i];
     i++;
    }
    hashval = hashval % 10;
    printf("\n Hashval returned in hash func= %d", hashval);
    return hashval;
}


struct list *lookup_string(struct hash_table *hashtable, char *str)
{
    printf("\n enters in lookup_string \n");
    printf("\n str in lookup_string = %s",str);

    struct list * new_list;
    unsigned int hashval = hash(hashtable, str);

    printf("\n hashval = %d \n", hashval);

    if(hashtable->table[hashval] == NULL)
    {
      printf("\n DEBUG ERROR :element not found in lookup string \n");
      return NULL;
    }

    /* Go to the correct list based on the hash value and see if str is
     * in the list.  If it is, return return a pointer to the list element.
     * If it isn't, the item isn't in the table, so return NULL.
     */


    for(new_list = hashtable->table[hashval]; new_list != NULL;new_list = new_list->next)
    {
        if (strcmp(str, new_list->string) == 0)
          return new_list;
    }
    printf("\n returns NULL in lookup_string \n");
    return NULL;
}


int add_string(struct hash_table *hashtable, char *str)
{
    printf("\n enters in add_string \n");

    struct list *new_list;
    struct list *current_list;
    unsigned int hashval = hash(hashtable, str);
    printf("\n hashval = %d", hashval);

    /* Attempt to allocate memory for list */
    if ((new_list = malloc(sizeof(struct list))) == NULL)
    {
     printf("\n enters here \n");
     return 1;
    }

    /* Does item already exist? */
    current_list = lookup_string(hashtable, str);

    if (current_list == NULL)
    {
     printf("\n DEBUG Purpose \n");
     printf("\n NULL \n");
    }

    /* item already exists, don't insert it again. */
    if (current_list != NULL)
    {
     printf("\n Item already present...\n");
     return 2;
    }

    /* Insert into list */
    printf("\n Inserting...\n");

    new_list->string = strdup(str);
    new_list->next = NULL;
    //new_list->next = hashtable->table[hashval];
    if(hashtable->table[hashval] == NULL)
    {
      printf("\n DEBUG1 : enters here \n");
      printf("\n hashval = %d", hashval);
      hashtable->table[hashval] = new_list;
    }
    else
    {
      printf("\n DEBUG2 : enters here \n");
      printf("\n hashval = %d", hashval);
      struct list * temp_list = hashtable->table[hashval];
      while(temp_list->next!=NULL)
       temp_list = temp_list->next;

      temp_list->next = new_list;
      // hashtable->table[hashval] = new_list;
    }

    return 0;
}

int delete_string(struct hash_table *hashtable, char *str)
{
    printf("\n enters in delete_string \n");

    struct list *new_list;
    struct list *current_list;
    unsigned int hashval = hash(hashtable, str);
    printf("\n hashval = %d", hashval);

    /* Does item already exist? */
    current_list = lookup_string(hashtable, str);

    if (current_list == NULL)
    {
     printf("\n DEBUG Purpose \n");
     printf("\n Item not present. So, cannot be deleted \n");
     return 1;
    }

    /* item exists, delete it. */
    if (current_list != NULL)
    {
    struct list * temp = hashtable->table[hashval];
    if(strcmp(temp->string,str) == 0)
    {
      if(temp->next == NULL)
      {
        hashtable->table[hashval] = NULL;
        free(temp);
      }
      else
      {
        hashtable->table[hashval] = temp->next;
        free(temp);
      }
    }
    else
    {
      struct list * temp1; 
      while(temp->next != NULL)
      {
        temp1 = temp; 

        if(strcmp(temp->string, str) == 0)
        {
          break;
        }
        else
        {
          temp = temp->next;
        }
      }
      if(temp->next == NULL)
      {
        temp1->next = NULL;
        free(temp);
      }
      else
      {
        temp1->next = temp->next;
        free(temp);
      }
    }
    }
    return 0;
}

void free_table(struct hash_table *hashtable)
{
    int i;
    struct list *new_list, *temp_list;

    if (hashtable==NULL) return;

    /* Free the memory for every item in the table, including the 
     * strings themselves.
     */
    for(i=0; i<hashtable->size; i++) {
        new_list = hashtable->table[i];
        while(new_list!=NULL) {
            temp_list = new_list;
            new_list = new_list->next;
            free(temp_list->string);
            free(temp_list);
        }
    }

    /* Free the table itself */
    free(hashtable->table);
    free(hashtable);
}

void view_hashtable(struct hash_table * hashtable)
{
    int i = 0;
    if(hashtable == NULL)
     return;

    for(i =0; i < hashtable->size; i++)
    {
        if((hashtable->table[i] == 0) || (strcmp(hashtable->table[i]->string, "*") == 0)) 
        {
            continue;
        }
        printf(" Index : i = %d\t String = %s",i, hashtable->table[i]->string);
        struct list * temp = hashtable->table[i]->next;
        while(temp != NULL)
        {
          printf("\t %s",temp->string);
          temp = temp->next;
        }

        printf("\n");
    }
}



int main()
{
    hashtable = create_hash_table(10);
    if(hashtable == NULL)
    {
     printf("\n Memory allocation failure during creation of hash table \n");
     return 0;
    }

    int flag = 1;

    while(flag)
    {
        int choice;

        printf("\n Press 1 to add an element to the hashtable\n");
        printf("\n Press 2 to delete an element from the hashtable\n");
        printf("\n Press 3 to search the hashtable\n");           printf("\n Press 4 to view  the hashtable\n");              printf("\n Press 5 to exit \n");
        printf("\n Please enter your choice: ");

        scanf("%d",&choice);

        if(choice == 5)
         flag = 0;

        else if(choice == 1)
        {
            char str[20];
            printf("\n Please enter the string :");
            scanf("%s",&str);
            int i;
            i = add_string(hashtable,str);

            if(i == 1)
            {
              printf("\n Memory allocation failure:Choice 1 \n");
              return 0;
            }
            else if(i == 2)
            {
              printf("\n String already prsent in hash table : Couldnot add it again\n");
              return 0;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("\n String added successfully \n");

            }
        }   


        else if(choice == 2)
        {
            int i;
            struct list * temp_list;
            char str[20];
            printf("\n Please enter the string you want to delete :");
            scanf("%s",&str);

            printf("\n String entered = %s", str);

            i = delete_string(hashtable,str);

            if(i == 0)
            {
              printf("\n Item found in list: Deletion success \n");
            }
            else
              printf("\n Item found in list: Deletion failed \n");
        }


        else if(choice == 3)
        {
            struct list * temp_list;
            char str[20];
            printf("\n Please enter the string :");
            scanf("%s",&str);
            temp_list = lookup_string(hashtable,str);

            if(!temp_list)
            {
              printf("\n Item not found in list: Deletion failed \n");
              return 0;
            }
            printf("\n Item found: Present in Hash Table \n");
        }


        else if(choice == 4)
        {
            view_hashtable(hashtable);
        }
        else if(choice == 5)
        {
            printf("\n Exiting ....");
            return 0;
        }
        else
         printf("\n Invalid choice:");
    };

    free_table(hashtable);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please format your code properly - there is a dedicated button for it.

Comment: I've reformatted your code, but it's still pretty long.  I wonder if it's possible to reduce it to a smaller program that exhibits the bug?  *Update* no it looks like I didn't (wonder how SO copes with simultaneous edits...) ;)

Comment: this code is way too long..first narrow it down to a manageable piece of code where it is failing.

Comment: @Edmund: there can be a message, that you are editing a post that was changed during your edit. But sometimes the time-window for this message is just too short. Last edit wins.

Comment: Did you really mean "I am ***able*** to understand the reason"?  If so, what is the problem?  If not, correct it.  I strongly suggest that you use a debugger rather than asking others to debug for you.  It will be far more efficient in the long term.

Answer (score 9):

Your hash function runs past the end of the string, just do e.g.

```
for(; *str != '\0'; str++)
{
 hashval += *str;

}
```

Comment: +1 Sharp eye indeed :-) It should also be noted that even this improved hash function is not spreading values very efficiently, i.e. it returns the same value for "abc", "bca", "cab" etc. To avoid this, the standard way is to multiply it with a prime in each step, e.g. `hashval *= 31; hashval += *str;`.

Comment: How different is this code from the one i wrote above? I think this is not the correct answer?

I have found the solution but not understood the root cause:

In hash function:
unsigned int hash(struct hash_table *hashtable, char *str) 
{ 

unsigned int hashval = 0;
char *p = str;
for(;*p!='\0';p++)
{
 hashval+= *p;
}

return hashval%10;
}

Comment: Your original code indexed str[i] but incremented both str and i, which makes it go past the end of str. Your code in the comment here(which in effect is 100% identical to what I posted) does not do that.